# Access - Select Distinct based on Field Value

Tags: vba, ms-access, distinct, distinct-on

### My Code

I have an Access query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID, "Awaiting Approval" AS RequestStatus
FROM [Request-Priority, ALL_Q] LEFT JOIN LIST_RequestBurndown_Q ON [Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID = LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.RequestID
WHERE (((LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.MilestoneStatus)="Awaiting Approval") AND (([Request-Priority, ALL_Q].[Completed on]) Is Null))

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT [Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID, "Blocked (see notes)" AS RequestStatus
FROM [Request-Priority, ALL_Q] LEFT JOIN LIST_RequestBurndown_Q ON [Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID = LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.RequestID
WHERE (((LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.MilestoneStatus)="Blocked (see notes)") AND (([Request-Priority, ALL_Q].[Completed on]) Is Null))

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT [Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID, "Completed - Awaiting Rollout" AS RequestStatus
FROM [Request-Priority, ALL_Q] LEFT JOIN LIST_RequestBurndown_Q ON [Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID = LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.RequestID
WHERE (((LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.MilestoneStatus)="Completed") AND (([Request-Priority, ALL_Q].[Completed on]) Is Null));
```

The basic concept of the query... based on the status of individual milestones (`LIST_RequestBurndown_Q.MilestoneStatus`), determine an overall status of a RequestID (`[Request-Priority, ALL_Q].RequestID`).

### My Issue

For some RequestID's, there will be milestones in more than one status. For example, I may get results like:

```
RequestID   RequestStatus 
123         Awaiting Approval 
243         Blocked 
243         Awaiting Approval 
243         Completed - Awaiting Rollout 
542         Awaiting Approval
```

What I would like to do is "prioritize" which `RequestStatus` displays so there is only one record per `RequestID`.

I've been trying to think of how to do this using `ORDER BY`, `WHERE`, `DISTINCT ON`, or possibly even just creating a table of the possible status options with an associated priority and using `MAX` - but at this point I'm just overthinking this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: a table to model the prioritization:

```
CREATE TABLE RequestStatusPrioritization
( RequestStatus VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
     REFERENCES RequestStatuses ( RequestStatus ),
  RequestStatusRank INT NOT NULL );
```

...then join to this table and return the lowest (`MIN`) rank.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I was thinking with respect to my 'associated priority' table that I could then use `MAX` in my query. I was hoping to avoid a table like that if there was a way to do it all with a single line of code in the query though.